# Как сохранить веб-страницу на диск?

Tags: python

То есть сделать то, что происходит при нажатии `Ctrl+S` в браузере.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Интернет не молчит, вы его просто не спрашивали.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

page = urlopen('https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html')

with open("test.html", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(page.read())
```

Comment: огромное спасибо

Comment: [Не благодарите автора ответа в комментариях. Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Для скачивания файлов есть функция urlretrieve: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve